# Issue with file upload form

Tags: php, html

So I'm building this control panel, and on one of the pages i've included a file upload input so the user could upload image.

The thing is, when I'm trying to upload an image called "jappinner.jpg" for an example, it works perfectly, but when I'm trying to upload an image called "ELECTRIC_2WAY_PLASTIC_WITH-Z.jpg" the form just crashes and no $_POST variables are posted to the action page.

I'm stuck with this issue for a while now, and I really can't figure it out..

Heres the form code :

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="submit" action="manage.php?page=products">
  <input type="hidden" name="new_product">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="product_name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter product name..">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="example-getting-started">Image</label><br />
        <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
  <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" /> 
 </div>

 
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="example-getting-started">Catalog</label><br />
        <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
  <input type="file" name="catalog" id="catalog" /> 
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="example-getting-started">Product Drawing</label><br />
        <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
  <input type="file" name="product_drawing" id="product_drawing" /> 
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="example-getting-started">Technical Information</label><br />
        <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
  <input type="file" name="technical_information" id="technical_information" /> 
 </div>
 
 
 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Category</label>
  <select id="category" name="category" class="form-control">
  <option value="agriculture">Agriculture</option>
  <option value="waterworks">Waterworks</option>
  <option value="fire_protection">Fire Protection</option>
  <option value="accessories_pilots">Accessories / Pilots</option>
</select>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group" id="agriculture_sub_categories">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Sub Category</label>
  <select name="sub_category" class="form-control">
  <option value="agriculture">Metal Valves</option>
  <option value="waterworks">Plastic Valves</option>
</select>
 </div>
 
  <div class="form-group" id="accessories_pilots_sub_categories">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Sub Category</label>
  <select name="sub_category" class="form-control">
  <option value="agriculture">Metal</option>
  <option value="waterworks">Plastic</option>
</select>
 </div>
 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="example-getting-started">Product Description</label>
 <textarea name="description" class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="Enter product description here.."></textarea>
 </div>
 
 
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
  <a href="manage.php?page=products" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

Heres the PHP code :

```
 if(isset($_POST['new_product'])) {

 function replaceAll($string, $array = array(), $rpl) {
 foreach($array as $value) {
 $string = str_replace($value, $rpl, $string);
 }
 return $string;
 }


$slogen = replaceAll($_POST['product_name'], array('#', ' ', "'", ':', '"', '_', '&', '/', '?', ')', '('), '_');
$slogen = replaceAll($slogen, array('--'), '_');

$columns = array('name', 'slogen', 'category', 'sub_category', 'description');
$values = array($_POST['product_name'], $slogen, $_POST['category'], '', $_POST['description']);
$db->Add('products', $columns, $values);
$new_product_id = $db->ID;


include "../core/plugins/flourish/init.php";

// Product Picture
if(isset($_POST['photo'])) {
$uploader = new fUpload();
$uploader->setMIMETypes(array('image/gif','image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/pjpeg','image/png'),'The file uploaded is not an image');
$file = $uploader->move('../dist/images/products/', 'photo');
$columns = array("file", "role", "product_id");
$values = array("dist/images/products/".$uploader->final_name, "image", $new_product_id);
$db->Add("product_files", $columns, $values);
}

// Product Catalog
if(isset($_POST['catalog'])) {
$uploader = new fUpload();
$uploader->setMIMETypes(array('application/pdf'),'The file uploaded is not an PDF');
$file = $uploader->move('../dist/files/', 'catalog');
$columns = array("file", "role", "product_id");
$values = array("dist/files/".$uploader->final_name, "catalog", $new_product_id);
$db->Add("product_files", $columns, $values);
}

// Product Product Drawing
if(isset($_POST['product_drawing'])) {
$uploader = new fUpload();
$uploader->setMIMETypes(array('application/pdf'),'The file uploaded is not an PDF');
$file = $uploader->move('../dist/files/', 'product_drawing');
$columns = array("file", "role", "product_id");
$values = array("dist/files/".$uploader->final_name, "product_drawing", $new_product_id);
$db->Add("product_files", $columns, $values);
}

// Product Technical Information
if(isset($_POST['technical_information'])) {
$uploader = new fUpload();
$uploader->setMIMETypes(array('application/pdf'),'The file uploaded is not an PDF');
$file = $uploader->move('../dist/files/', 'technical_information');
$columns = array("file", "role", "product_id");
$values = array("dist/files/".$uploader->final_name, "technical_information", $new_product_id);
$db->Add("product_files", $columns, $values);
}


//redirect("manage.php?page=products&msg=new_product_success");
```

}

Comment: Where's the php code that handles the upload?

Comment: Not relevant as the PHP code is fine. The thing is that when I'm trying to upload the "ELECTRIC_2WAY_PLASTIC_WITH-Z.jpg" image, no $_POST variables are posted at all.

EDIT : I included the php code, just in case

Comment: thing is here, you're treating your files as POST; wrong superglobal.

Comment: Okay - I fixed it and i'm still having the same problem. What you need to understand is the PHP is not the problem here. The $_POST variables doesn't even make it to the PHP code, the form is literally crashing..

Answer (score 0):

We're dealing with `$_FILES` here and not `$_POST`.

You need to change

```
if(isset($_POST['photo']))
```

to

```
if(isset($_FILES['photo']))
```

and do the same for all the other ones.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

- If it's crashing, check your logs.

**Also make sure the folder(s) have proper permissions to write to it.**

---

Another thing, your form tag contains `name="submit"` as does your submit button; that would be a conflict.

Plus, forms do not hold the name attribute, and should be removed from it.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment.
As I already told you, I changed the $_POST to $_FILES but i'm still having the same problem.

What i'm trying to say is that the PHP code is not related in this situation. My problem is that the form is literally crashing, so no $_POST variables actually makes it (Then the PHP code is not triggered ).

Its something related to the form itself, I don't know what it is..

Comment: @AmirMendelson You're welcome. I noticed something else in your form. Reload my answer, near the bottom of it.

Comment: I've included the name attribute as a desperate action trying to solve this problem. Just in case, I removed it. The issue still occurs.